# Docker Image push to google container registry not working

Tags: docker, containers, registry, push

When i push a image from a jenkins to gcr following error occurs:
denied: Unable to write blob sha256

Even if i set the registry public it is not possible. The same error occurs

Comment: Can you provide what commands you ran

Comment: docker push eu.gcr.io/<projectname>/...

Comment: I have also added the credentials to my jenkins as described here https://itnext.io/setup-jenkins-with-google-container-registry-2f8d39aaa275

Comment: It had even worked some time but after two pushes it hasn't worked anymore, and I don't know what has changed

Comment: Update: If I connet to the pod/container with exec / sh, it is possible to push the image to gcr (with exactly the sam commands)...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to figure out the solution for this Stephan?

Comment: yes it was a problem with my permissions on the storage. Your service account needs write permissions. If this doesn't work, check if your worker is allowed to write in the registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem sounded likewise. First, I managed to temporary fix it with @michael-bouvy's solution above, by manual deleting the conflicting images.

What have I done to fix it permanently is adding **permission** in GC IAM to the appropriate custom role of the identity that performs pushing. Namely, in addition to existing ones:

```
storage.buckets.get
storage.objects.create
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.list
```

I appended two more:

```
storage.objects.delete
storage.objects.update
```

Basically, these permissions just looked like those that required for temporary manual operations.

Comment: Adding the additional permissions to the service account solves the issue. For the record: so far, the problem seems to appear when using BuildKit only (e.g. by setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`) and not for the regular Docker build engine.

Answer (score 4):

I've been facing the same issue, and eventually solved it by removing the problematic Docker image layer, using the Console UI: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/artifacts..appspot.com/containers/images/

Error message looks like:

```
denied: Unable to write blob sha256:050eee1aec04cc914bf96e8f4dee7767510c2aca3816af6078ba6fbe3150920e
```

File name in the artifacts bucket will match exactly the blob name: `sha256:050eee1aec04cc914bf96e8f4dee7767510c2aca3816af6078ba6fbe3150920e`.

Delete it, and try again. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for location hint. Basically I could not find the exact sha. I ended up deleting all containers, images and uploads as searching one preventing file would take too much time. Anyway, it started working again on clean contaiters-images-uploads

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was re-tagging and pushing the offending image to a different registry.

The push to the alternate registry worked on the first attempt and subsequent pushes for the same image to the original registry suddenly started working.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below command to push to Google container registry.

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'google_crd_file', variable: 'filekey')]) {
                        sh """
                        gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${filekey}
                        gcloud auth configure-docker
                        docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io < $filekey
                        docker push eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<VERSION>
                      """
```

"google_crd_file" is the ID of the credential stored in the Jenkins.